# Does bounty apply to a CW question?

Tags: support, bounty, community-wiki

On [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1653/what-does-your-super-awesome-desktop-look-like-screenshots) question the OP opened a bounty, however the question is Community Wiki. Should bounty's still apply to these questions?

**Edit**
To clarify I am trying to determine if the bounty will actually be allocated for a Community Wiki questions which does not allow reputation gain.

Comment: That post had just been flagged by another user and I was thinking this same question myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bounty does not care whether the question is CW or not and will be awarded if it meets the rules.

The "normal" votes on the answers are subject to regular CW rules.

Comment: but who gets the bounty if multiple people edit it?

Answer (score 3):

Of course it should. The OP is still looking for an answer, and they've staked their own rep to find one. This is basically a cash transaction.

Comment: "What does your super awesome desktop look like?" is a question that needs a bounty?

Comment: However a community wiki does not gain any reputation. It is defined as a question with no concrete answer?

Comment: I posted the bounty to put extra attention to a post that I liked - subjective as it was. I think the bonus rep is not necessarily fair, but I think its a valid way to spend my reputation.

Comment: @TheTXI. I think the question is utterly ridiculous. But there is someone out there who is looking for an answer, and they want to spend their hard earned rep to get it.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think it should. You can't get upvote reputation for your answer, why should you be able to get a bounty for something that is likely to be subjective?

Comment: You can get upvotes...you just don't get reputation.

Comment: Right, that's of course what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/unified-way-to-scrape-html-from-any-type-of-browser-process/484312#484312) the OP accidentally hit CW.  The question resulted in some good answers not getting any rep.  I think the answers still deserved the rep from the bounty given the technical nature of the question (although I am biased...)