# Clarification about bounty award allocation for a community wiki post

Tags: support, bounty, community-wiki

I see this "[How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)" and see it states that "*One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty*".

I look over some of the answers there and see most of them are community wiki so this has me a little curious where the bounty award is allocated if the bounty poster awards to a community wiki answer.

**My Question**

If a community wiki answer is awarded a bounty, does the OP get the award or how does that work?

Comment: This is one of those where lots can relate to needing this sort of solution to get a visual of this space and so many answers are to use third party apps. The wording of that question though does not seem to ask for an app even though most of the answers are just that.

Comment: My reason was that somebody recently suggested a specific program (WizTree), and I recently directed/commented/requested information from one of those programs (author of the question figured out the problem themselves).  Any event I wanted to reward the user who suggested WizTree.  Nothing more, nothing less, **the Community Wiki question exists, by the way, to answer "what is using all my storage space" type questions.**  So the question serves a purpose, even though, it's a software recommendation. Similar to the "how to remove malware" question that is also full of SRs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, bounties can be awarded to community wiki answers.  The restriction on reputation gain applies only to voting.  See this Meta post: [Does bounty apply to a CW question?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/263/does-bounty-apply-to-a-cw-question).

The thread linked in that Meta post was subsequently deleted (visible to 10K users).  It had 5,472 views, the question had 34 upvotes, it received 62 answers, the accepted answer (and bounty winner) had 109 upvotes.  And it was the poster child for an off-topic question (hence the deletion).

BTW, the deleted thread raises a related question on bounties: What happens if a bounty is awarded and the answer is later deleted (does the answerer get to keep the bounty)?

Answer: When an answer that received a bounty gets deleted, all reputation including the bounty are revoked, and the bounty is not given back to the user who awarded it.

- Exception: if the answer had a score of at least 3, and was visible for at least 60 days at the time of deletion, the bounty award is kept.
- Recent new exception: If the question is deleted (taking the answers with it), and the bounty is not retained by the answerer per the previous exception, the bounty is refunded to the offerer.  See [Changes to bounty rules: removal of double rep-retention, blocking of owner deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306966/changes-to-bounty-rules-removal-of-double-rep-retention-blocking-of-owner-dele)

For a comprehensive explanation of bounties, see: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)